# Transaction atomic with Django signals

Tags: python, django

Inside the transaction atomic block am updating table1 and creating table2. Where table2 use foreign key of table1. Table1 is updated successfully and table 2 is created. But when django signals of table2 is called, am getting the old instance of table1.

I need the latest instance of table1 inside Django signals.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.